# PL/SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE of block with no SQL, stored procedure or function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I wrote a stored procedure to strip non-alphanumeric characters from an input term as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CleanTerm(
  p_Cleaned OUT VARCHAR,
  p_Input VARCHAR
)
IS
BEGIN
  p_Cleaned := REGEXP_REPLACE( p_Input, '[^ 0-9A-Za-z]', '');
END;
```

Now I need to execute this procedure with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, which is not hard, given that I can bind my local variables to the ones declared in the stored procedure

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN CleanTerm(:1, :2); END;'
  USING l_Cleaned, l_Raw;
```

Is there a way to do the same thing without defining a stored procedure? Something like

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "BEGIN :1 := REGEXP_REPLACE( :2, '[^ 0-9A-Za-z]', ''); END;"
  USING l_Cleaned, l_Raw;
```

Of course this does not work. There are no input or output variables to bind the placeholders. I get

> PLS-00201: identifier 'BEGIN :1 := REGEXP_REPLACE( :2, '[^ 0-9A-Za-z]', ''); END;' must be declared

Comment: You don't need anything dynamic here, so please clarify what is the purpose of `execute immediate`. Just put this same block of code into your current PL/SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
DECLARE
  l_Raw     VARCHAR2(4000) := 'something';
  l_Cleaned VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "BEGIN :1 := REGEXP_REPLACE( :2, '[^ 0-9A-Za-z]', ''); END;"
    USING l_Cleaned, l_Raw;
  -- Do something with l_cleaned
END;
/
```

Fails because double quotes are for identifiers and you want single quotes, which are for string literals (and to escape the single quotes in the string) and because you have not declared an `OUT` bind variable:

```sql
DECLARE
  l_Raw     VARCHAR2(4000) := 'something';
  l_Cleaned VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :1 := REGEXP_REPLACE( :2, ''[^ 0-9A-Za-z]'', ''''); END;'
    USING OUT l_Cleaned, l_Raw;
  -- Do something with l_cleaned
END;
/
```

However, you can just use the PL/SQL anonymous block without `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` as there is nothing dynamic about what you are trying to execute:

```
DECLARE
  l_Raw     VARCHAR2(4000) := 'something';
  l_Cleaned VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  l_Cleaned := REGEXP_REPLACE( l_raw, '[^ 0-9A-Za-z]');
  -- Do something with l_cleaned
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

`Execute immediate` requires PL/SQL; you can't just "execute" it (e.g. at SQL level).

Here's an example; see if it helps.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_input  varchar2(20) := 'L#it%/lef"oot';
  3    l_result varchar2(20);
  4  begin
  5    execute immediate q'{select regexp_replace(:b, '[^ 0-9A-Za-z]', '') from dual}'
  6      into l_result using l_input;
  7
  8    dbms_output.put_line('Result = ' || l_result);
  9  end;
 10  /
Result = Litlefoot

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Or, another option, ran in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> var b varchar2(20)
SQL> exec :b := 'L#it%/lef"oot';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> var result varchar2(20)
SQL> exec :result := regexp_replace(:b, '[^ 0-9A-Za-z]', '');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print result

RESULT
--------------------------------
Litlefoot

SQL>
```